# An alternative way to integrate derivatives of inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm getting through my book for calculus and I tried to evaluate

$$A = \int_{-1}^{+1} {x^2 - {2 \over {x^2 + 1}}} \space dx \tag1$$

on my own, as I forgot that $\int{1 \over x^2 + 1} = \tan^{-1}(x) + c$. I wonder, however, why didn't I get the same result when going the other way (using substitution for $x^2 + 1$).

$$A = \int_{-1}^{+1} {x^2} dx - 2\int_{-1}^{+1}{1 \over {x^2 + 1}} dx \tag2$$
Choosing $u = x^2 +1$ and $du = 2x\space dx$, I turned the above into
$$A = \Bigg[\space {x^3 \over 3} \space\Bigg]_{-1}^{+1}  - 2\int_{2}^{2}{1 \over u} {1 \over {2x}}du \tag3$$
and because $2 = 2$, $A$ becomes 
$$A = {2 \over 3}\tag4$$

If I do 
$$A = {2 \over 3} + -2\Bigg[\space \tan^{-1}(x) \space\Bigg]_{-1}^{+1} = {2 \over 3} -\pi/2 - \pi/2 = {2 \over 3} - \pi\tag5$$

The answer in my book is ${2\over3} - \pi$ too. I must have $M$essed something up, but I don't know what and where.

Would there be some ideas?

Comment: Where did that u-sub come from? What happened to your limits of integration? That's where the problem is. Also, in the end, arctan(1)-arctan(-1) is not 0.

Comment: Oh, hack, a copy paste! Sorry, will edit it.

Comment: @Harry, slowdown with those edits, you're flooding the front page. Do 3 or 4, not a dozen in 20 minutes, then go do something else for a while, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $u$-sub is off. If $u = x^2+1$ then $du = 2x\text{d}x$. But there is no $2x$ term in your integral, so you'll need to solve for $x$ using $u$. You'll get $x = \sqrt{u-1}$, meaning $2\text{d}x = \frac{\text{d}u}{\sqrt{u-1}}$ and $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{2}{x^2 + 1}\space \text{d}x = \int \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u-1}}\text{d}u$$ This integral in terms of $u$ is also not so easy to integrate.

---

Instead, I would begin with $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{2}{x^2 + 1}\space \text{d}x$ and use trig-sub. Imagine a right triangle with angle $\theta$, opposite leg length $x$ and adjacent leg length of $1$. Then the hypotenuse of this triangle will have length $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, meaning:

$$\sec^2(\theta) =x^2+1 \\ \tan(\theta) = x \\ \sec^2(\theta)d\theta = dx$$ and plugging all this in yields $$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2}{x^2 + 1}\space \text{d}x = 2\int_{/}^/ \frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)}\cdot \sec^2(\theta)d\theta  =2\int_{/}^/ d\theta  =2\Bigg[\theta +C\Bigg]_{/}^/$$ from the equation $\tan(\theta) = x$ we then know $\theta = \arctan(x)$, so $$2\Bigg[\theta +C\Bigg]_{/}^/ = 2\Bigg[\arctan(x)+C\Bigg]_{-1}^1$$ yielding the expected result.

Comment: Ok, but knowing that I would eventually integrate from $2$ to $2$, will it change anything?

Comment: I think you will actually integrate from $0$ to $2$. Integrating from $2$ to $2$ will always give you zero. Your choice of $u$ makes it difficult to plug in values and find new limits of integration. I'd recommend solving the $u$-sub integral, then converting back to $x$ and evaluating at the original limits.

Comment: Solving the u-sub integral again means doing another substitution, or?

Comment: @user35443 looks like another substitution would be required based on the choice of $u$ you started with. But I would guess another substitution would give you an integral that looks like the one you started with, which wouldn't be helpful. I think this is just one of those integrals you have to recognize :) I'll try to see if I can solve it a different way without using the argument that I know $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx = \arctan(x)+C$

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter then. It seems there are some thing I just have to learn the hard way. Thank you.

Comment: @user35443 I shouldn't have been so hasty with my words, there is usually more than one way to skin a cat! I figured out another way to do it. I edited my post to include how. It uses trig-sub, if you are familiar with it!

Comment: :-) Thank you again for your effort. Trigonometric substitution is something we don't have in our books, it's nice to know that such thing exists.

Comment: @user35443 seriously no trig sub??? That is a shame. It's so useful, and gives you a way to solve a whole host of integrals that are difficult otherwise